# Mixing django-celery and standalone celery

Tags: django, celery

We are running a website built with Django and Piston and I want to implement celery to offload tasks to an external server. I don't really want to run Django on the secondary server and would like to simply run a pure Python celery worker. Is it possible for me to write simple function stubs on the Django server and write the actual function logic on the secondary server?

i.e.

Django Side

```
from celery import task

@task
send_message(fromUser=None, toUser=None, msgType=None, msg=None):
    pass
```

Server Side

```
from celery import Celery
celery =  Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
@celery.task
send_message(fromUser=None, toUser=None, msgType=None, msg=None):
    # Do send_message logic here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is easily possible.

If you have a pure-python Celery worker, you can send tasks by name
as long as you use the same broker URL:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

then in some view:

```
 celery.send_task('send_message', kwargs={
     'fromUser': ...,
 })
```

Comment: I was hoping to still use the django-celery settings on the Django side, but I may implement raw celery on both sides as there seems to be some additional database stuff that django-celery does that I don't completely understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also schedule your tasks in configuration with CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'scheduled_task':{
            'task':'name in your task decorator',
            'schedule': timedelta(...),
            'args': (..., ),
        }
    }
```

But your worker has to be run with celery beat (`-B`):

```
celery -A app.tasks worker -B -l info
```