# Using celery with django app and backend server

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a follow-on / clarification question related to an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920974/mixing-django-celery-and-standalone-celery)

I have 2 servers (for now).  1 server runs a django web application.  The other server runs pure python scripts that are CRON-scheduled data acquisition & processing jobs for the web app.

There is a use case where user activity in the web application (updating a certain field) should trigger a series of actions by the backend server.  I could stick with CRON but as we scale up, I can imagine running into trouble.  Celery seems like a good solution except I'm unclear how to implement it. (Yes, I did read the getting started guide).

I want the web application to send tasks to a specific queue but the backend server to actually execute the work.

Assuming that both servers are using the same broker URL,

Do I need to define stub tasks in Djando or can I just use the `celery.send_task` method?
Should I still be using django-celery?

Meanwhile the backend server will be running Celery with the full implementation of the tasks and workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try it and work through any issues that came up.

On my django server, I did not use `django-celery`.  I installed `celery` and `redis` (via pip) and followed most of the instructions in the [First Steps with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html):

- updated `proj/proj/settings.py` file to include the bare minimum of
  configuration for Celery such as the `BROKER_URL`
- created the `proj/proj/celery.py` file but without the task defined
  at the bottom
- updated the `proj/proj/__init__.py` file as documented
- Since the server running django wasn't actually going to execute any
  Celery tasks, in the view that would trigger a task, I added the
  following:

`from proj.celery import app as celery_app`

`try:
     # send it to celery for backend processing
     celery_app.send_task('tasks.mytask', kwargs={'some_id':obj.id,'another_att':obj.att}, queue='my-queue')
 except Exception as err:
     print('Issue sending task to Celery')
     print err`

The other server had the following installed: `celery` and `redis` (I used an AWS Elasticache redis instance for this testing).
This server had the following files:

- `celeryconfig.py` will all of my Celery configuration and queues
  defined, pointing to the same `BROKER_URL` as the django server
- `tasks.py` with the actual code for all of my tasks

The celery workers were then started on this server, using the standard command: `celery -A tasks worker -Q my-queue1,my-queue2`

For testing, the above worked.  Now I just need to make celery run in the background and optimize the number of workers/queue.

If anyone has additional comments or improvements, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: You can use supervisor to control celery and other processes http://supervisord.org/